# Get table row index and row data in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have a table in HTML, which is created as follows:

```
<table id="tableID" onclick="getRowData()" class="table table-hover"></table>
```

At first it gets populated with some initial data, which could make it look something like this:

```
From  Action  To
 a      1     b
 a      0     a
```

I want to be able to retrieve the data from an arbitrary row, just by clicking on that row on the webpage. I also want to be able to retrieve the row index from that row as well. For example, if I would want to get the data from the first row, then I would get `a 1 b`

How would such a function look like?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to have `getRowData()` in the table element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You have to place your click handler on the rows and not on the table.

Since your table is dynamically generated, attaching the click handlers from Typescript/JavaScript might be easier, here is a way to do it.

Use [`document.querySelector('#tableID')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get a reference to your table.

Then, there are two ways to get a reference to the table rows and cells:

- Use [`table.querySelectorAll('tbody td')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) to query the rows in the table DOM. Then use `row.querySelectorAll('td')` to get the cells.
- Use the table DOM API (see @H.B. comment below) to avoid querying the DOM for each row and each cell. With this technique you can get the rows with `table.tBodies[0].rows` and the cells with `row.cells`.

Then use [`element.addEventListener('click', handler)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach the click handlers to every row.

Here is a JavaScript demo with detailed comments:

```js
// get a reference to your table by id
// cast this to HTMLTableElement in TypeScript
const table = document.querySelector('#tableID');

// get all rows in the first table body
const rows = table.tBodies[0].rows;

// convert the rows to an array with the spread operator (...)
// then iterate over each row using forEach
Array.from(rows).forEach((row, idx) => {
  // attach a click handler on each row
  row.addEventListener('click', event => {
    // get all cells in the row, convert them to an array with the spread operator (...)
    // then for each cell, return its textContent by mapping on the array
    const tds = Array.from(row.cells).map(td => td.textContent);

    console.clear();
    // Log the row index
    console.log('row index:', idx);
    // Log the tds content array
    console.log('tds content:', ...tds);
    // join the contents of the tds with a space and display the string
    console.log('tds string:', tds.join(' '));
  });
});
```

```html
<table id="tableID">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>From</th><th>Action</th><th>To</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>1</td><td>b</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>0</td><td>a</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also, in your TypeScript code, do not forget to cast the result of `document.querySelector('#tableID')` to `HTMLTableElement` to get the correct typing:

```
const table: HTMLTableElement = document.querySelector('#tableID');
```

[**See the TypeScript demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-table-row-click)

Comment: You could use the table DOM API, which i would prefer to always querying. I.e. to get rows => `table.tBodies[0].rows`, to get cells => `row.cells`. (In TypeScript you need to cast the result of the first query to `HTMLTableElement`.)

Comment: @H.B., Thank you for the comment, do you mind if I update my answer ?

Comment: Not at all, go ahead.

Comment: @jo_va when I try to follow your code example, I get the following error `type <HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLTableRowElement> is not an array type` when I try to use the spread operator, [...rows]. What should the type be?

Comment: @Stiiq, I updated the code and included a typescript demo, hope that helps

Comment: @jo_va Thanks a lot, I think I found the mistake. I was targeting ES5 and not ES6.

Comment: @jo_va quick question, how do I correctly store the information that the variable `tds` contains? I seem to only get `undefined` whenever I try

Comment: @Stiiq, this depends on how you intend to use the information. You could set a global variable, there are many ways to do it

Comment: @jo_va The code you provided I have put inside a function, and within this function I want a variable of somesort, to store the information that `tds` contains, and then I want that information to be returned whenever I call this function. What would be a smart solution to that?